# Mocking using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to write `Mockito` test case to get the `plantIDs` and perform some processing.
I added the test case too.

This is my test case

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PlantDetailsServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks PlantDetailsService service;
    @Mock   PlantDetailsHelper helperMock;
    @Mock   HttpURLConnection conn;
    @Mock   BufferedReader buf;
    @Mock   InputStream input;
    @Mock   InputStreamReader ir;
    @Mock   JSONObject json;
    @Mock   JSONArray arr;
    @Mock   List<String> plantResult;


    @Test
    public void TestGetPlantDetails() throws Exception
    {
         String plantID1= "23";

         List<String> plantResult = new ArrayList<String>(); 
         plantResult.add(plantID1);
         Mockito.when(helperMock.getPlantIds()).thenReturn(plantResult);
         URL url = new URL("**********/23");
         conn=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
         Mockito.when((HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection()).thenReturn(conn);
         Mockito.when(conn.getResponseCode()).thenReturn(200);
         input=conn.getInputStream();
         Mockito.when(conn.getInputStream()).thenReturn(input);
         ir=new InputStreamReader(input);
         Mockito.when(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream()))).thenReturn(ir);
         buf=new BufferedReader(ir);
         Mockito.when(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())))).thenReturn(buf);
         String output=buf.readLine();
         Mockito.when(buf.readLine()).thenReturn(output);
         json=new JSONObject(output);
         Mockito.when(new JSONObject(output)).thenReturn(json);
         arr=json.getJSONArray("Data");
         Mockito.when(json.getJSONArray("Data")).thenReturn(arr);
         assertThat(output,is(notNullValue()));
         List<PlantDetailsDTO> plantDetailsList=new ArrayList<PlantDetailsDTO>();
         plantDetailsList=service.getPlantDetails();

    }
}
```

This throws an error in the line where I read `InputStream()`.I can't open connection because URL might be a final class. I get an error in `openConnection()` line too.. Missing method invocation.

Comment: Is your `helperMock` object `null` when you get the error?

Comment: Null Pointer exception at  com.test.PlantDetailsServiceTest.TestGetPlantDetails(PlantDetailsServiceTest.java:57)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have forgotten to add one of two configuration details which would enable the annotations mocking:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PlantDetailsServiceTest {
```

or

```
@Before
public void init(){
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Without those, mockito does not instantiate the @Mock's and thus you get null pointer exception.

Comment: Thank You it worked but explored new problems. Can i post the code?

Comment: Go ahead.. lets see

Comment: m8.. that method is not ready for unit testing.. not even close. What you need to do is to refactor it and create a few helper classes which would specialize in doing certain parts of that algorithm. Then you would unit test those small public method of those classes. If you try to test that method as it is right now.. even if that is possible.. noone would understand those tests and in the future those tests would just be ignored. I know refactoring is painful but thats the only way to test legacy code like that.

Comment: Can I just write junit test case and assert to check the return value

Comment: To get to any assertion of that method code.. you will need to mock / spy and prepare a lot of other dependencies and data.. Unit tests are natural verifiers of good clean code.. if its hard to name a unit test or it starts to be bloated with data preparation then something is wrong with your code and you simply have to refactor and work on prod code first before you get down to unit testing